# determine a class attribute is Property?

Tags: python, descriptor

Is there a way to determine a class attribute is a `Property` (with `__get__` and `__set__` or not?
The method in 
[Determine if given class attribute is a property or not, Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735520/determine-if-given-class-attribute-is-a-property-or-not-python-object) looks like only work for `property` decorator, which is not work in my case.

```
class Property(object):
    _value = None
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._value 
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._value = value * 2


class A(object):
    b = Property()

>>> a = A()
>>> type(A.p)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(a.p)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: The correct term is 'descriptor'. See the [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your descriptor returns `None` because it is *also* invoked for classes (the `instance` attribute is set to `None` when `__get__` is called for that scenario).

You need to retrieve it *without* invoking the descriptor protocol, reaching into the class `__dict__` attribute is the most direct path:

```
A.__dict__['p']
```

See the [Python Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for more details on how and when descriptors are invoked.

Alternatively, do as the `property` object does and return `self` when `instance` is set to `None` (so when accessed on a class):

```
class Property(object):
    _value = None
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self._value 
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._value = value * 2
```

Also see [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

Demo:

```
>>> class Property(object):
...     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
...         return self._value 
...     def __set__(self, instance, value):
...         self._value = value * 2
... 
>>> class A(object):
...     b = Property()
... 
>>> A.__dict__['b']
<__main__.Property object at 0x103097910>
>>> type(A.__dict__['b'])
<class '__main__.Property'>
>>> class Property(object):
...     _value = None
...     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
...         if instance is None:
...             return self
...         return self._value 
...     def __set__(self, instance, value):
...         self._value = value * 2
... 
>>> class A(object):
...     b = Property()
... 
>>> A.b
<__main__.Property object at 0x10413d810>
```

Comment: Great explanation, and the reference article is useful!!